# Display 4 current/live times from different timezones that update with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, timezone

I want to display 4 timezones, GMT (BST now), CET, EST, PST, on a webpage. These times should update 'live' so the hour/minute counter updates.

<s>I almost have this working but in my JS only the first time updates live and not the following three.</s>

**Resolved the above in edited post.** I will review and move (or delete/report) in Code Review. My bad.

As an aside, with the exception of the `timeZone` all four timezones use the same settings. I wondered if there is a better way of writing this to reduce the amount of script or is this approach fine?

```js
const timeGMT = document.getElementById("timeGMT");
const optsGMT = {
    hour: '2-digit',
    minute: '2-digit',
    timeZone: 'Europe/London',
    hour12: false,
    timeZoneName: 'short'
};

const timeCET = document.getElementById("timeCET");
const optsCET = {
    hour: '2-digit',
    minute: '2-digit',
    timeZone: 'Europe/Amsterdam',
    hour12: false,
    timeZoneName: 'short'
};

const timeEST = document.getElementById("timeEST");
const optsEST = {
    hour: '2-digit',
    minute: '2-digit',
    timeZone: 'America/New_York',
    hour12: false,
    timeZoneName: 'short'
};

const timePST = document.getElementById("timePST");
const optsPST = {
    hour: '2-digit',
    minute: '2-digit',
    timeZone: 'America/Los_Angeles',
    hour12: false,
    timeZoneName: 'short'
};
  
const showDateTime = () => {
timeGMT.textContent = new Date().toLocaleString('en-GB', optsGMT); 
timeCET.textContent = new Date().toLocaleString('en-GB', optsCET);
timeEST.textContent = new Date().toLocaleString('en-US', optsEST)
timePST.textContent = new Date().toLocaleString('en-US', optsPST); }

showDateTime();
setInterval(showDateTime, 1000);
```

```html
<p class=sidebar__time>
<span id="timeGMT"></span>
&nbsp; — &nbsp;
<span id="timeCET"></span>
&nbsp; — &nbsp;
<span id="timeEST"></span>
&nbsp; — &nbsp;
<span id="timePST"></span>
</p>
```

Comment: Need to put your 4 `timeGMT.textContent = ...` statements in curly braces `{}`.

Comment: Ahhhh god. Silly me, still learning. Would you say the code is sound other than that, no need to shorten/needs to be this way. If so I can delete...

Comment: Can be shortened, but that's more of a code review question.

Comment: That's cool, it's just for a POC so I'll leave for now. Thanks for the quick reply/info!

Comment: Also, setInterval will be drifting and not keeping the time correcty, you should consider using requestAnimationFrame https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame

Comment: Thanks I'll update that as well. Numerical value (1000) seems OTT/not needed as well?